# Velocity calling a vararg method

Tags: java, velocity

I am trying to call a varargs method from Velocity.
The function is defined in a Class named "Abc" as:

```
public static void function(String ... values)
```

I set the context as

```
params.put("concat",new Abc());
```

The template contains the call to the method as:

```
$concat.function('Var1','var2')
```

If I fix the function to have one argument everything works fine, if I move to the varargs (or a `byte[]` for that matter), it can't resolve it and I don't get back what I wanted. I set some log settings and go that velocity gets:

```
Null reference [template 'bufferTemplate', line 1, column 1] :
  $concat.function('Kuku','Muku') cannot be resolved.
```

Comment: Which Velocity version are you using?

Comment: Is your Abc class declared public?

Answer (score 3):

I am using Velocity 1.6.4 and for me it works the way you've written! Update your Velocity! As far as I have seen they have support for `varags` from version 1.6 !

Answer (score 3):

Got it. I'm using axis, which seems to be using an older version of Velocity. Once velocity was set first in the classpath, it works.
Thanks for the help.