# In Maven, how do I discover what is depending on a particular dependency?

Tags: java, linux, maven, maven-3

I've got [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4666338/velocity-calling-a-vararg-method) and I think it's caused by some library transitively depending on an old version velocity.  My pom is explicitly asking for the correct version of velocity, but I think some other dependency is transitively pulling in an old version of velocity and this is being used in my classpath instead.

I'm aware of `mvn dependency:tree`, but on a complex project, this can output a very tall, difficult to read tree.  It's more thinking than I'd like to figure out what's depending on velocity 1.5, for example.

So I figured, "grep to the rescue".  But that didn't help because I got this output:

```
$ mvn dependency:tree | grep velocity
[INFO] |  |  +- velocity:velocity:jar:1.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- velocity:velocity:jar:1.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- velocity:velocity:jar:1.5:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.velocity:velocity:jar:1.6.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.velocity:velocity-tools:jar:2.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- velocity:velocity:jar:1.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- velocity:velocity:jar:1.5:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.velocity:velocity-tools:jar:2.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.velocity:velocity:jar:1.6.3:compile (version managed from 1.6.2)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- velocity:velocity:jar:1.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.velocity:velocity-tools:jar:2.0:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.velocity:velocity:jar:1.6.3:provided (version managed from 1.6.2)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- velocity:velocity:jar:1.5:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.velocity:velocity-tools:jar:2.0:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.velocity:velocity:jar:1.6.3:provided (version managed from 1.6.2)
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.velocity:velocity-tools:jar:2.0:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.velocity:velocity:jar:1.6.3:provided (version managed from 1.6.2)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- velocity:velocity:jar:1.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.velocity:velocity:jar:1.6.3:compile (version managed from 1.6.3)
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.velocity:velocity-tools:jar:2.0:compile (version managed from 2.0)
[INFO] |  |  +- velocity:velocity:jar:1.5:compile
```

I can't tell what's really depending on that first velocity 1.5 there.  Does maven provide some arguments to `dependency:tree` to make my life easier?  Or is there some neat trick I can use with the shell commands to figure this out?  I'm using cygwin btw, but I'm hoping that doesn't matter since it has most of those commands available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this should help you (taken from [Resolving conflicts using the dependency tree](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree.html))

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=velocity
```

If that does not help I'd prefer filtering on dependency over grep (taken from [Filtering the dependency tree](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/filtering-the-dependency-tree.html))

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dincludes=velocity:velocity
```

Answer (score 1):

[cheffe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18345966/317951) is a good one.

To add to this, another solution I use often involves `egrep`, basically when I want to see the bigger picture.

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose | egrep --color 'velocity|$'
```

Pros:

- colored output
- partial matching of words (since it's just grep).

Cons:

- the verbosity of the output